# QT-C++ errors implementing live555 in qt application

Tags: c++, qt, live555

I'm using QT5.02 on ubuntu 12.04 and the last release of live555.

This is my class (CameraStream.cpp) that will read the rtsp stream:

```
#include "CameraStream.h"
#include <DummySink.h>
#include <ourRTSPClient.h>
#include "liveMedia.hh"
#include "BasicUsageEnvironment.hh"

CameraStream::CameraStream(){
    eventLoopWatchVariable = 0;

    // Begin by setting up our usage environment:
    TaskScheduler* scheduler = BasicTaskScheduler::createNew();
    UsageEnvironment* env = BasicUsageEnvironment::createNew(*scheduler);

    openURL(*env, "argv[0]", "rtsp://admin@192.168.1.99:1234/file.sdp");

    // All subsequent activity takes place within the event loop:
    env->taskScheduler().doEventLoop(&eventLoopWatchVariable);

}

#define RTSP_CLIENT_VERBOSITY_LEVEL 1 

static unsigned rtspClientCount = 0; 

void CameraStream::openURL(UsageEnvironment& env, char const* progName, char const* rtspURL) {

    RTSPClient* rtspClient = ourRTSPClient::createNew(env, rtspURL, RTSP_CLIENT_VERBOSITY_LEVEL, progName);
    if (rtspClient == NULL) {
        env << "Failed to create a RTSP client for URL \"" << rtspURL << "\": " << env.getResultMsg() << "\n";
        return;
    }

    ++rtspClientCount;

    rtspClient->sendDescribeCommand(continueAfterDESCRIBE);
}


// Implementation of the RTSP 'response handlers':

void CameraStream::continueAfterDESCRIBE(RTSPClient* rtspClient, int resultCode, char* resultString) {
    do {
        UsageEnvironment& env = rtspClient->envir(); // alias
        StreamClientState& scs = ((ourRTSPClient*)rtspClient)->scs; // alias

        if (resultCode != 0) {
            env << *rtspClient << "Failed to get a SDP description: " << resultString << "\n";
            delete[] resultString;
            break;
        }

         char* const sdpDescription = resultString;
         env << *rtspClient << "Got a SDP description:\n" << sdpDescription << "\n";

        // Create a media session object from this SDP description:
        scs.session = MediaSession::createNew(env, sdpDescription);
        delete[] sdpDescription; // because we don't need it anymore
        if (scs.session == NULL) {
            env << *rtspClient << "Failed to create a MediaSession object from the SDP description: " << env.getResultMsg() << "\n";
            break;
        } else if (!scs.session->hasSubsessions()) {
            env << *rtspClient << "This session has no media subsessions (i.e., no \"m=\" lines)\n";
            break;
         }

         scs.iter = new MediaSubsessionIterator(*scs.session);
         setupNextSubsession(rtspClient);
         return;
    } while (0);

    // An unrecoverable error occurred with this stream.
    shutdownStream(rtspClient);
}

// By default, we request that the server stream its data using RTP/UDP.
// If, instead, you want to request that the server stream via RTP-over-TCP, change the following to True:
#define REQUEST_STREAMING_OVER_TCP False

void CameraStream::setupNextSubsession(RTSPClient* rtspClient) {
    UsageEnvironment& env = rtspClient->envir(); // alias
    StreamClientState& scs = ((ourRTSPClient*)rtspClient)->scs; // alias

    scs.subsession = scs.iter->next();
    if (scs.subsession != NULL) {
        if (!scs.subsession->initiate()) {
            env << *rtspClient << "Failed to initiate the \"" << *scs.subsession << "\" subsession: " << env.getResultMsg() << "\n";
            setupNextSubsession(rtspClient); // give up on this subsession; go to the next one
        } else {
            env << *rtspClient << "Initiated the \"" << *scs.subsession
            << "\" subsession (client ports " << scs.subsession->clientPortNum() << "-" << scs.subsession->clientPortNum()+1 << ")\n";

            // Continue setting up this subsession, by sending a RTSP "SETUP" command:
            rtspClient->sendSetupCommand(*scs.subsession, continueAfterSETUP, False, REQUEST_STREAMING_OVER_TCP);
        }
        return;
    }

    // We've finished setting up all of the subsessions.  Now, send a RTSP "PLAY" command to start the streaming:
    if (scs.session->absStartTime() != NULL) {
        // Special case: The stream is indexed by 'absolute' time, so send an appropriate "PLAY" command:
        rtspClient->sendPlayCommand(*scs.session, continueAfterPLAY, scs.session->absStartTime(), scs.session->absEndTime());
    } else {
        scs.duration = scs.session->playEndTime() - scs.session->playStartTime();
        rtspClient->sendPlayCommand(*scs.session, continueAfterPLAY);
    }
}

void CameraStream::continueAfterSETUP(RTSPClient* rtspClient, int resultCode, char* resultString) {
    do {
        UsageEnvironment& env = rtspClient->envir(); // alias
        StreamClientState& scs = ((ourRTSPClient*)rtspClient)->scs; // alias

        if (resultCode != 0) {
            env << *rtspClient << "Failed to set up the \"" << *scs.subsession << "\" subsession: " << resultString << "\n";
            break;
        }

        env << *rtspClient << "Set up the \"" << *scs.subsession
        << "\" subsession (client ports " << scs.subsession->clientPortNum() << "-" << scs.subsession->clientPortNum()+1 << ")\n";

        // Having successfully setup the subsession, create a data sink for it, and call "startPlaying()" on it.
        // (This will prepare the data sink to receive data; the actual flow of data from the client won't start happening until later,
        // after we've sent a RTSP "PLAY" command.)

        scs.subsession->sink = DummySink::createNew(env, *scs.subsession, rtspClient->url());
        // perhaps use your own custom "MediaSink" subclass instead
        if (scs.subsession->sink == NULL) {
            env << *rtspClient << "Failed to create a data sink for the \"" << *scs.subsession
            << "\" subsession: " << env.getResultMsg() << "\n";
            break;
        }

        env << *rtspClient << "Created a data sink for the \"" << *scs.subsession << "\" subsession\n";
        scs.subsession->miscPtr = rtspClient; // a hack to let subsession handle functions get the "RTSPClient" from the subsession
        scs.subsession->sink->startPlaying(*(scs.subsession->readSource()),
                                       subsessionAfterPlaying, scs.subsession);
    // Also set a handler to be called if a RTCP "BYE" arrives for this subsession:
        if (scs.subsession->rtcpInstance() != NULL) {
            scs.subsession->rtcpInstance()->setByeHandler(subsessionByeHandler, scs.subsession);
        }
    } while (0);
    delete[] resultString;

    // Set up the next subsession, if any:
    setupNextSubsession(rtspClient);
}

void CameraStream::continueAfterPLAY(RTSPClient* rtspClient, int resultCode, char* resultString) {
    Boolean success = False;

    do {
        UsageEnvironment& env = rtspClient->envir(); // alias
        StreamClientState& scs = ((ourRTSPClient*)rtspClient)->scs; // alias

        if (resultCode != 0) {
            env << *rtspClient << "Failed to start playing session: " << resultString << "\n";
            break;
        }

        // Set a timer to be handled at the end of the stream's expected duration (if the stream does not already signal its end
        // using a RTCP "BYE").  This is optional.  If, instead, you want to keep the stream active - e.g., so you can later
        // 'seek' back within it and do another RTSP "PLAY" - then you can omit this code.
        // (Alternatively, if you don't want to receive the entire stream, you could set this timer for some shorter value.)
        if (scs.duration > 0) {
            unsigned const delaySlop = 2; // number of seconds extra to delay, after the stream's expected duration.  (This is optional.)
            scs.duration += delaySlop;
            unsigned uSecsToDelay = (unsigned)(scs.duration*1000000);
            scs.streamTimerTask = env.taskScheduler().scheduleDelayedTask(uSecsToDelay, (TaskFunc*)streamTimerHandler, rtspClient);
        }

        env << *rtspClient << "Started playing session";
        if (scs.duration > 0) {
            env << " (for up to " << scs.duration << " seconds)";
        }
        env << "...\n";

        success = True;
    } while (0);
    delete[] resultString;

    if (!success) {
        // An unrecoverable error occurred with this stream.
        shutdownStream(rtspClient);
    }
}


// Implementation of the other event handlers:

void CameraStream::subsessionAfterPlaying(void* clientData) {
    MediaSubsession* subsession = (MediaSubsession*)clientData;
    RTSPClient* rtspClient = (RTSPClient*)(subsession->miscPtr);

    // Begin by closing this subsession's stream:
    Medium::close(subsession->sink);
    subsession->sink = NULL;

    // Next, check whether *all* subsessions' streams have now been closed:
    MediaSession& session = subsession->parentSession();
    MediaSubsessionIterator iter(session);
    while ((subsession = iter.next()) != NULL) {
        if (subsession->sink != NULL) return; // this subsession is still active
    }

    // All subsessions' streams have now been closed, so shutdown the client:
    shutdownStream(rtspClient);
}

void CameraStream::subsessionByeHandler(void* clientData) {
    MediaSubsession* subsession = (MediaSubsession*)clientData;
    RTSPClient* rtspClient = (RTSPClient*)subsession->miscPtr;
    UsageEnvironment& env = rtspClient->envir(); // alias

    env << *rtspClient << "Received RTCP \"BYE\" on \"" << *subsession << "\" subsession\n";

    // Now act as if the subsession had closed:
    subsessionAfterPlaying(subsession);
}

void CameraStream::streamTimerHandler(void* clientData) {
    ourRTSPClient* rtspClient = (ourRTSPClient*)clientData;
    StreamClientState& scs = rtspClient->scs; // alias

    scs.streamTimerTask = NULL;

    // Shut down the stream:
    shutdownStream(rtspClient);
}

void CameraStream::shutdownStream(RTSPClient* rtspClient, int exitCode) {
    UsageEnvironment& env = rtspClient->envir(); // alias
    StreamClientState& scs = ((ourRTSPClient*)rtspClient)->scs; // alias

    // First, check whether any subsessions have still to be closed:
    if (scs.session != NULL) {
        Boolean someSubsessionsWereActive = False;
        MediaSubsessionIterator iter(*scs.session);
        MediaSubsession* subsession;

        while ((subsession = iter.next()) != NULL) {
            if (subsession->sink != NULL) {
                Medium::close(subsession->sink);
                subsession->sink = NULL;

                if (subsession->rtcpInstance() != NULL) {
                    subsession->rtcpInstance()->setByeHandler(NULL, NULL); // in case the server sends a RTCP "BYE" while handling "TEARDOWN"
                }

                someSubsessionsWereActive = True;
            }
        }

        if (someSubsessionsWereActive) {
            // Send a RTSP "TEARDOWN" command, to tell the server to shutdown the stream.
            // Don't bother handling the response to the "TEARDOWN".
            rtspClient->sendTeardownCommand(*scs.session, NULL);
        }
    }

    env << *rtspClient << "Closing the stream.\n";
    Medium::close(rtspClient);
    // Note that this will also cause this stream's "StreamClientState" structure to get reclaimed.

    if (--rtspClientCount == 0) {
        // The final stream has ended, so exit the application now.
        // (Of course, if you're embedding this code into your own application, you might want to comment this out,
        // and replace it with "eventLoopWatchVariable = 1;", so that we leave the LIVE555 event loop, and continue running "main()".)
        exit(exitCode);
    }
}

UsageEnvironment& operator<<(UsageEnvironment& env, const RTSPClient& rtspClient) {
    return env << "[URL:\"" << rtspClient.url() << "\"]: ";
}

UsageEnvironment& operator<<(UsageEnvironment& env, const MediaSubsession& subsession) {
    return env << subsession.mediumName() << "/" << subsession.codecName();
}
```

And this is the file header (CameraStream.h):

```
#ifndef CAMERASTREAM_H
#define CAMERASTREAM_H

#include <liveMedia.hh>


class CameraStream
{
public:
    CameraStream();

private:
    // Forward function definitions:

    // RTSP 'response handlers':
    void continueAfterDESCRIBE(RTSPClient* rtspClient, int resultCode, char* resultString);
    void continueAfterSETUP(RTSPClient* rtspClient, int resultCode, char* resultString);
    void continueAfterPLAY(RTSPClient* rtspClient, int resultCode, char* resultString);

    // Other event handler functions:
    void subsessionAfterPlaying(void* clientData); // called when a stream's subsession (e.g., audio or video substream) ends
    void subsessionByeHandler(void* clientData); // called when a RTCP "BYE" is received for a subsession
    void streamTimerHandler(void* clientData);
    // called at the end of a stream's expected duration (if the stream has not already signaled its end using a RTCP "BYE")

    // The main streaming routine (for each "rtsp://" URL):
    void openURL(UsageEnvironment& env, char const* progName, char const* rtspURL);

    // Used to iterate through each stream's 'subsessions', setting up each one:
    void setupNextSubsession(RTSPClient* rtspClient);

    // Used to shut down and close a stream (including its "RTSPClient" object):
    void shutdownStream(RTSPClient* rtspClient, int exitCode = 1);

    char eventLoopWatchVariable;
};
// A function that outputs a string that identifies each stream (for debugging output).  Modify this if you wish:
UsageEnvironment& operator<<(UsageEnvironment& env, const RTSPClient& rtspClient) ;

// A function that outputs a string that identifies each subsession (for debugging output).  Modify this if you wish:
UsageEnvironment& operator<<(UsageEnvironment& env, const MediaSubsession& subsession);


#endif // CAMERASTREAM_H
```

when i try to compile i get the following error:

```
../CameraProva/CameraStream.cpp: In member function 'void CameraStream::setupNextSubsession(RTSPClient*)':
../CameraProva/CameraStream.cpp:110:112: error: no matching function for call to 'RTSPClient::sendSetupCommand(MediaSubsession&, <unresolved overloaded function type>, const Boolean&, const Boolean&)'

../CameraProva/CameraStream.cpp:110:112: note: candidate is:
../include/RTSPClient.hh:85:12: note: unsigned int RTSPClient::sendSetupCommand(MediaSubsession&, void (*)(RTSPClient*, int, char*), Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Authenticator*)

../include/RTSPClient.hh:85:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'void (*)(RTSPClient*, int, char*)'
../CameraProva/CameraStream.cpp:118:124: error: no matching function for call to 'RTSPClient::sendPlayCommand(MediaSession&, <unresolved overloaded function type>, char*, char*)'

../CameraProva/CameraStream.cpp:118:124: note: candidates are:
../include/RTSPClient.hh:93:12: note: unsigned int RTSPClient::sendPlayCommand(MediaSession&, void (*)(RTSPClient*, int, char*), double, double, float, Authenticator*)

../include/RTSPClient.hh:93:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'void (*)(RTSPClient*, int, char*)'
../include/RTSPClient.hh:99:12: note: unsigned int RTSPClient::sendPlayCommand(MediaSubsession&, void (*)(RTSPClient*, int, char*), double, double, float, Authenticator*)

../include/RTSPClient.hh:99:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'MediaSession' to 'MediaSubsession&'
../include/RTSPClient.hh:109:12: note: unsigned int RTSPClient::sendPlayCommand(MediaSession&, void (*)(RTSPClient*, int, char*), const char*, const char*, float, Authenticator*)

../include/RTSPClient.hh:109:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'void (*)(RTSPClient*, int, char*)'
../include/RTSPClient.hh:112:12: note: unsigned int RTSPClient::sendPlayCommand(MediaSubsession&, void (*)(RTSPClient*, int, char*), const char*, const char*, float, Authenticator*)

../include/RTSPClient.hh:112:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'MediaSession' to 'MediaSubsession&'
../CameraProva/CameraStream.cpp:121:68: error: no matching function for call to 'RTSPClient::sendPlayCommand(MediaSession&, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
../CameraProva/CameraStream.cpp:121:68: note: candidates are:
../include/RTSPClient.hh:93:12: note: unsigned int RTSPClient::sendPlayCommand(MediaSession&, void (*)(RTSPClient*, int, char*), double, double, float, Authenticator*)

../include/RTSPClient.hh:93:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'void (*)(RTSPClient*, int, char*)'
../include/RTSPClient.hh:99:12: note: unsigned int RTSPClient::sendPlayCommand(MediaSubsession&, void (*)(RTSPClient*, int, char*), double, double, float, Authenticator*)

../include/RTSPClient.hh:99:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'MediaSession' to 'MediaSubsession&'
../include/RTSPClient.hh:109:12: note: unsigned int RTSPClient::sendPlayCommand(MediaSession&, void (*)(RTSPClient*, int, char*), const char*, const char*, float, Authenticator*)

../include/RTSPClient.hh:109:12: note:   candidate expects 6 arguments, 2 provided
../include/RTSPClient.hh:112:12: note: unsigned int RTSPClient::sendPlayCommand(MediaSubsession&, void (*)(RTSPClient*, int, char*), const char*, const char*, float, Authenticator*)

../include/RTSPClient.hh:112:12: note:   candidate expects 6 arguments, 2 provided
../CameraProva/CameraStream.cpp: In member function 'void CameraStream::continueAfterSETUP(RTSPClient*, int, char*)':
../CameraProva/CameraStream.cpp:153:82: error: no matching function for call to 'MediaSink::startPlaying(FramedSource&, <unresolved overloaded function type>, MediaSubsession*&)'

../CameraProva/CameraStream.cpp:153:82: note: candidate is:
../include/MediaSink.hh:34:11: note: Boolean MediaSink::startPlaying(MediaSource&, void (*)(void*), void*)
../include/MediaSink.hh:34:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'void (*)(void*)'

../CameraProva/CameraStream.cpp:156:95: error: no matching function for call to 'RTCPInstance::setByeHandler(<unresolved overloaded function type>, MediaSubsession*&)'
../CameraProva/CameraStream.cpp:156:95: note: candidate is:
../include/RTCP.hh:59:8: note: void RTCPInstance::setByeHandler(void (*)(void*), void*, Boolean)

../include/RTCP.hh:59:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'void (*)(void*)'
../CameraProva/CameraStream.cpp: In member function 'void CameraStream::continueAfterPLAY(RTSPClient*, int, char*)':
../CameraProva/CameraStream.cpp:185:100: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the '&' ?)

make: *** [CameraStream.o] Error 1
```

i copy the code from the example of the testRTSPClient in the source archive of live555. what i'm doing wrong? There is any examples of QT applications that use live555?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the callbacks in the RTSPClient class or change the function signature of sendSetupCommand and sendPlayCommand (and probably others) to take a function pointer that's within the CameraStream class.